# Is it possible to use Media Fire API from Google Sites or WordPress Website?

Tags: wordpress, api, file-upload, google-sites, mediafire

I'm a beginner in web development, I want to create a website that will have a very large number of file uploads, a single could be up to 100 MB.

I want the upload to be through my website but the upload destination to be on MediaFire (I'm looking for unlimited free storage, using several MediaFire accounts). I still haven't given the MediaFire API a try, but I want to know if with some lines of code I can create a FileUpload on my website but the destination be on MediaFire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Fire Api is a Library Php right ?  On google sites, you can add Php File with App engine.

I don't know it's possible but , I think this link can help you.
http://www.sitepoint.com/google-app-engine-php-getting-started/